# Problems with Apple id

Tags: apple-id

i set up my son's mini iPad with my Apple id thus i could keep track of The purchases. Now i can only download apps on his mini iPad And not on my iPad nor iPhone ;( What can I do to fin this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since your phone only really talks to Apple's servers - you can sign out of your Apple ID in the store section of the settings App. Then check the date and time on the device (it needs to be somewhat close to the time on the servers for the security to work - within a minute should be fine) and then sign in again.